# Defining function with return value as another class in Java

Tags: java, class, oop, java-8

I was reading one piece of code in Java and one function definition caught my eye. Its a long piece of code so I am just putting a abstract version to know how it worked.

Consider I have a file A.java with below code.

```
abstract public class A
{
  public B method1()
  {
   .....
   }
  abstract public boolean  method2();
  if (method2())   // Is this valid . If yes , what is the concept behind it?
  {.....}   
}
```

Now I have file B.java with below sample contents

```
public class B extends A 
{
  @Override
  public boolean method2() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Now I am a beginner in Java but from what I have learned that I can call method2 in class B since it extends A. But how can I have return value of a class B in parent class A defined as return value of function method1. Please help me in clearing this concept. I am totally bounced over this piece of code.

Comment: What exactly does "I'm totally bounced over this piece of code" mean? The code should compile and run with no problem. Whether it is good design to have a return type of subclass B in your superclass A is of course another question, but its totally valid java and I don't quite understand your actual problem.

Comment: I think you are worried about circular dependency. How can A depend on B (A returns B means A need to know what B is) when B depends on A (B extends A means B need to know what A is).
It's a bad design, but it works in java.

Comment: Unrelated but: "I can call method2 in class B since it extends A" not quite. Since `method2` doesn't have any visibility modifier it is set as "package-private" so only classes in *same* package as `A` will be able to call it. If `B extends A` but is in *other* package it will not be able to access `method2` *directly*.

Comment: Anyway what is the problem which prevents you from accepting fact that `method1` was declared to return `B`? Methods can declare to return *any* type, so why not `B`?

Comment: @Pshemo  normally I have encountered programs where class that extends the parent class , methods can be accessed from parent class. The other way around is new to me. And yes both classes are in the same package

Comment: "I have encountered programs where class that extends the parent class , methods can be accessed from parent class. The other way around is new to me." <- But that isn't the case here. A isn't accessing any methods from B. It's just declaring B as a return type for his own method. That's something completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question

Here's the code you posted (edited slightly to tidy it up, but the structure is the same):

```
abstract public class A {
  public B method1() { ... }
  void method2() {};
}

public class B extends A {
  ...
}
```

You asked this question:

> *how can I have return value of a class B in parent class A defined as return value of function method1?*

Specifically, you are asking how "method1()" on class A can return B, when B itself is a class which extends A:

```
abstract public class A {
  public B method1() { ... }
```

#### Explanation

The reason this works is that the *return type* of `method1()` – and in general, *any* method defined in class A – has nothing to do with the *class structure* of A *or* B.

The return type simply means if you call `method1()`:

- there is a result from that method call,
- the result is an object,
- and the object has type "B"

It does *not* say anything about *how* (or even *if*) B relates to A.

Methods can specify any return types (so long as that type is valid.. you can't just return things which don't exist). Here's a simple edit of class A showing a few other return types. These additional return types are clearly unrelated to class A – String and `List<Integer>`.

```
abstract class A {
    abstract public B method1();
    abstract public String method2();
    abstract public List<Integer> method3();
}
```

In this new "A", all it says is:

- method1() returns something of type B, whatever that is
- method2() returns something of type String
- method3() returns `List<Integer>`

It's fine if B itself is defined in terms of A (`class B extends A`), or is altogether defined as a separate class. Here's a version of B, but without "extends A", so it's just a standalone class definition, this would work fine with your definition of A, too.

```
class B {
}
```

#### More reading

Here are a few snips from the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) about method definitions:

> *The only required elements of a method declaration are the method's return type, name, a pair of parentheses, (), and a body between braces, {}.*

and also:

> *The return type—the data type of the value returned by the method, or void if the method does not return a value.*

There's an additional section possibly worth reading - [Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) – which has more discussion about how this works, what's allowed, etc.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation . Regarding methods I have one more query . I have edited the question . Suppose I have a abstract boolean method declared in class A but defined in another class B under annotation Override . Can I call straight away that method in class A ?

Comment: @isilia: that's really a completely different question and should be asked separately. But the short answer is yes: you can call `abstract` methods just like any other methods, because Java makes sure that when you have an instance of that type it's guaranteed to have an implementation of that method somewhere.

Comment: @isilia If this answer addressed your original question, please consider [voting and accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it. If you have a different question, it is best to open a new question with those details.